# Length of the state of vuex doesn't come out

Tags: vue.js, vuex

There is a state in the vuex.

I defined 'images' as an array and when I print by console.log(state.images), the result came out like below.

```
[__ob__: Observer]
0: {…}
1: {…}
2: {…}
3: {…}
4: {…}
length: 5
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(5), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

After that, when I use `console.log(state.images[0])` or `console.log(state.images.length)` doesn't work. Could you recommend some solution? Thank you so much for reading this.

EDIT) I write more code in detail.

```
const state = {
    images:[]
};

const mutations = {
    pushPresentImage(state, yo) {
        state.images.push(yo);
},

const actions = {
    imageLoad() {

    },

    imageLength({commit}, image){
        axios.post('/', ...)
           .then(result =>{ 
                commit('pushPresentImage', result.data.image)
            })
           .then(() => {
                console.log(state.images) // it works well like above.
                console.log(state.images[0]) // it says undefined.. 
            })
},
```

Comment: please provide more code

Comment: I wrote some code more. But this is normal procedure that i did before. but in this case happen this problem. So I have not figured out the problem yet..

Comment: where do you put `console.log(state.images)`?

Comment: Oh sorry. I wrote down more in detail.

Comment: i recommend to access state inside a mutation not in actions

Comment: I tried it. but the result is same. ..

Comment: did you try getters ?

Comment: Yes. I tried everthing. It has 5 values as an array. But when I use [0] or length , it doesn't have anything.. So it' s weird situation..

Comment: `imageLength ({ commit, state }, image)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are reading the `state.images[0]` array when the state is not fully saved by vuex. But I tried with the same code you used and it worked for me. Try restructuring your state so it does not stand alone:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    todos: []
  },
  mutations: {
    pushPresentImage(state, yo) {
      state.todos.push(yo);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    imageLoad() {},
    imageLength({ commit, rootState }, image) {
      axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        .then(result => {
          commit("pushPresentImage", result.data);
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log(rootState.todos); // it works well like above.
          console.log(rootState.todos[0]); // it does not say undefined..
        });
    }
  }
});

export default store;
```

Here is the sample code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-pg60h?fontsize=14)

Comment: Thank you so much. I restructured again thanks to you.